# pdo_mysql crashes PHP on windows

Tags: php, mysql, windows, pdo, crash

I've been having a problem with using pdo_mysql on Windows. (Also tried with mysqli briefly.)
It works fine on my Debian server. But since my work's computers are set up with wamp or xampp servers (tried both) I can't really ignore a windows-only problem.

Specifically this is the code I have problems with:

```
$sql  = "SELECT `TABLE_NAME`, `TABLE_ROWS` FROM "
      . "`information_schema`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = "
      . ":schema AND `TABLE_NAME` NOT LIKE 'stf_%'";
$stmt = self::$pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':schema', self::$settings['schema']);
$stmt->execute();
$tables = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->closeCursor();
unset($sql,$stmt);
$return = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($tables); $i++) {
    $table = $tables[$i]['TABLE_NAME'];
    $rows = $tables[$i]['TABLE_ROWS'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$table}`";
    $stmt = self::$pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    // This piece fails in Windows:
    $return[$table][] = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // I've also tried using loops with fetch.
    // They work for a few rows and then crash.
    unset($table,$sql,$stmt);
}
var_dump($return);
```

What happens is it gets the name of the tables in a certain schema and then is supposed to pull all the content of those tables into the `$return` array. When `fetchAll` failed I tried various loops, everything from `foreach` to `while` to `for` and it always results in PHP crashing at some point or another.

When In some tables with more than a couple rows after a certain number of rows PHP suddenly crashes without producting any errors in any logs. I have my logs set to the highest debugging levels since this is a development environment.

Here's exactly what I get when it fails:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>       Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2015 13:55:29 GMT
>       Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8
>       X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.8
>       Last-Modified: 
>       Accept-Ranges: bytes
>       Content-Length: 0
>       X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
>       X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>       Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
>       Connection: Keep-Alive
>       Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

Due to which I haven't been able to figure it out.

Essentially the I'm trying to take a badly written old schema and organize it in PHP in a way that conforms with our new schema. So I can do a single call for a certain piece of data and get it independent of whether the DB uses the old or new Schema. So... Backward compatibility, basically.

Anyway, here's a link to the data I get from the Debian server using the same code. (Proof it works!)
http://deviousconcepts.com/

Comment: I'm thinking it may be related to the amount of data returned. Since tables that have less data per row return more rows. Will check it out and see if I can figure out the data limit.